# How to display an Android gridview within a tabbed layout

Tags: android, android-layout, tabbed-view

Hi I'm setting up an android app and I'm using a tabbed interface.  I'd like three tabs, a text based tab (About), a webkit tab (Store) and a gridview tab of images (Gallery) like in the [Gridview tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

I have the text and webkit tab working fine, but I cannot figure out the best way to format the gridview within the tab.  Using the [tabbed interface tutrial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) as an example, I am declaring the tab's content within the onCreate() event of the main class.

```
public class Woodroid extends TabActivity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AboutActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("about").setIndicator("",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_about))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StoreActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("store").setIndicator("Store",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_store))
            .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GalleryActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("gallery").setIndicator("Gallery",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_gallery))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

So then in the GalleryActivity.java I have the following

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            GridView gridview = new GridView(this);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            setContentView(gridview);
     }
}
```

Which is an interpretation from the gridview tutorial.  The thing that is missing then is the gridview layout definition.  It seems I can force some of the attributes like
`gridview.setNumColumns(3);`
but that does not allow for the more flexible looking equivelant from the /layout/main.xml of the gridview version

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use a FrameLayout, c.f. [tabbed example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), set android:layout_width="WRAP_CONTENT" instead of fill_parent and then play with gravity and weight on each object element until it looks how you want it to.

Comment: That does the job of wrapping the content.  THANKS!  But there are other elements not universal to all tabs.  Like would I set the default image size, column width and such explicitly in the java rather than the xml?

Comment: Yes, for those I find it best to put those in java and not in the xml.